# Teams Deeplink - hyperlink in message

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I am trying to send messages to Teams (chat with user) via [deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links). I succeeded at first, like a year ago. Without a change in my code, it suddenly stopped working. The link gets pasted as simple text without highlighting and it’s annoying.
I tried
`[link name](link)` and `<a href="link">link name</a>`  syntax (encoded or raw), but nothing helps.

Is there a way to paste hyperlinks to Teams via deeplink, that will be active?

I use `return $"{openIn}l/chat/0/0?users={emails}&message={System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("test  [test](https://adaptivecards.io) test")}";` for preparing link.

so result url looks like this
`http://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=aaa@bbb.com&message=test+%5btest%5d(https%3a%2f%2fadaptivecards.io)++test`

Teams in compose box just shows link that is not clickable/transformed.

[Teams compose box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFlT7.png)

Comment: Can you please share screenshots of it. Meanwhile we will also try it from my end.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I edited the question and added the code that composes the link

Comment: @Robert-We are unable to repro the scenario. Are you tried the same thing? if not then Could you please share the repro steps ,so we can tried it from our end?
https://youtu.be/LPb3Kn3sqok
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#markdown-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited question once more. Added result link and picture of compose box after using it. I cannot open that youtube video as its marked as private :(

Comment: Here is link- https://youtu.be/ugTXTvvSu6U

Comment: I watched the video and we really don’t understand each other. :) I wanted to prepare message for the user with hyperlinks in message. User can send it to another user right away and this hyperlink is active/clickable. We have scenario when we open Teams from our WebApp and we want to send hyperlink to request detail, so other user knows context of what whole conversation is about.

Comment: we are unable to repro the scenario,It's looking fine for us [![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DFVa.png
Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.8170 (64-bit). 
Could you please check it once?

Comment: I have 1.5.00.5967 (64-bit). Can you share your deeplink, because I cannot get it work, after opening http://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=aaa@bbb.com&message=test+%5btest%5d(https%3a%2f%2fadaptivecards.io)++test (change email) I get message in compose box, but link is inactive. Could it be some kind of security think on our tenant? Thanks, for your patience.

Comment: Here is deeplink:-https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=ABC@M365x881222.OnMicrosoft.com&topicName=TestChat&message=Hello
please change the user name as per your tenant.

Comment: Got the reply from engineering team that, this is By design - we do not support this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Deeplink:-
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=ABC@xyz.com&topicName=TestChat&message=Hello

Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.8170 (64-bit).

please change the user ID as per your tenant.

Ref.Doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

Comment: Once again, this is working. But put hyperlink as message parameter and see what is in your compose box after opening that deeplink. I have hyperlink that looks like simple text. User has to format it himself.

Comment: I am not talking about pasting whole deeplink into compose box. Your deeplink works fine. It shows "Message" in compose box. Have you tried using my deeplink. http://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=aaa@bbb.com&message=test+%5btest%5d(https%3a%2f%2fadaptivecards.io)++test? Maybe that will tell you where is problem :)

Comment: ok. got it. We are checking it internally and let you know.

Comment: I just asked a question related to this but I'm trying to do this on a Teams Channel which seems to be different. It's not called a chat but a conversation. "&message=" does not work with channels. Is there another option for Channels/Conversations? Thanks

Comment: @Verminous- Please have look into this for channel conversation-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-deep-links-to-channel-conversation

Comment: We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Do you have any news regarding this bug?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Engineering team working on this issue. Currently we don’t have ETA or Update on this thread. We will let you know once we have any updates on it. Thanks.

Comment: Not fix yet? I have the same issue,, deeplinks doesn't work on mobile but works on Desktop

Comment: Got the reply from engineering team that, this is By design - we do not support this functionality.