# Start "NEW CONVERSATION" in a channel with list of questions on the text box

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

So I do this all the time during the day where I ask for assistance in a MS Teams channel:
I need to message the team with a template so I open a .TXT file copy paste the list of questions:

```
1. Short description
2. Which troubleshooting did you do?
3. Which articles did you check?"
```

and so on...

I'd like to be able to just use a shortcut/favourite on my browser that immediatly opens this MS Teams channel on browser window and has the list of questions/template already pasted in the chat box so I can just type in the answers. Is this doable? If so how, if now what is the closest solution possible to what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

EDIT:
So I found this question:
[Teams Deeplink - hyperlink in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71570964/teams-deeplink-hyperlink-in-message)

It seems this function is called deeplinks.
In my cause the solution presented does not work for Channels.
Is there another way to use deeplinks in this form on Teams Channels?

Comment: Please have look into this for channel conversation-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-deep-links-to-channel-conversation

Answer (score 1):

Use this deep link format to navigate to a particular conversation within channel thread:

> https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message//?tenantId=&groupId=&parentMessageId=&teamName=&channelName=&createdTime=

Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-deep-links-to-channel-conversation

Comment: Thing is I want to open a new one with a text template. I tried all possible forms. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the things which you have want to try?

Comment: I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with shortcuts/HYPERLINKS on some cells, for applications used in the company. One of the tasks I have is to ask for assistance on a certain Teams channel. I want to use a link / deeplink to this channel so that when I click the HYPERLINK in sheets, it opens a new tab for the Teams Channel with the Text box already prepared with a template/text so I only have to type or copy paste certain things. I don't want to open my TXT file and copy paste the template into Teams everytime I need it. I thought that using deeplinks function could do this.

Comment: Here is sample for tab deeplink-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-deeplink/csharp